# unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell with properly defined identifier

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I experienced weird issue with TableViewController

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3694.4.18/UITableView.m:7732
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

It makes no sense while
[image]

Identifier is set properly.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
```

However if i place

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

in ViewDidLoad, then it works. However prototype from storyboard will not and is not used.

At this point i have no idea what's going on.
TableViewController class is set also correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't created your view controller from the storyboard.  Is this the initial view controller?  If not, then how did you create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that issue was in custom library i was using for navigation. Instead initialising view controller from storyboard identifier, it was initialising class directly, thus storyboard view controller was useless.

Everything works well now.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question, There are only one reason that your tableview can not find the registered cell.

Solution is that you have to check your code one more time. Please check your identifier spelling in both storyboard and cellForRowAt method.

if this solution not work than follow this steps:

1. paste below code in cellForRowAt method

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

   return cell
2. Delete all cells from tableviewcontroller from storyboard.
3. Drag and drop new TableViewCell and give proper indetifer "cell"
4. Build and run.

   This solution will definitely work.

Comment: Hi, i tried this already. Spelling if for sure fine, both have "cell", tried also different names. I did also tried to completely remove cell, add it again, also limited code in cellForRowAt only to tableView.dequeueReusableCell. Cleaning project also didn't helped.

Comment: Use different identifier instead of "cell".If this solution is not work then my advice is that create new demo project and create UItableViewController in that project, If everything is fine then after use that code in your origional project

Comment: I tried. I was able to make it work in test project only for this purpose. But when i create new TableViewController inside my project and create class, then this problem arises back again. Not sure what can i do now.

Comment: Ohhh,  I think this problem occur due to UiTableViewController. Can you try UiViewController  instead of UiTableViewController? Drag and Drop UITableView to UiViewController. And try different identifier like "cell1", "cell2" etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you using a TableViewCell Differently So I am sure you had also created a tableCell Class , as in my case its `"CustomTableCellClass"` as follow

```
class CustomTableCellClass: UITableViewCell {

    weak var CategoriesDelegate: CategoriesVcDelegate?
    weak var itemsDelegate: ItemsvcDelegate?


    //MARK: Outlets of CategoriesVcTableView
    @IBOutlet weak var ProductImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ProductName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ProductPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ProductStarImage: UIButton!

}
```

My cellReuseIdentifier Declaration -

```
 let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
```

Now Deque it as

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.CategoriesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! CustomTableCellClass

    cell.CategoriesDelegate = self
    cell.ProductStarImage.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.ProductName.text = productNameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.ProductPrice.text = productPriceArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.ProductImage.image = productImagesArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Still this won't solve my problem as i will have few prototypes, not all custom ones. While even basic one does not work.

Comment: Are you  taking a seperate class for tableCell ?